# Cannot create Report Type

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have the following objects:

```
Contact
Linked Contacts
```

The `Linked Contacts` is an object that groups certain `contacts`.
I want to be able to create a report type of `contacts with or without Linked contacts`, however it seems that I can only create a report type of `linked contacts with contacts`.

Any ideas how I can create a report with `contact with or without linked contacts`?

Tia, Lily.

Comment: I got confused, you have written contacts everywhere expect line number 2 ?

Comment: Linked Contacts is an object that groups contacts.